# How to change point styles in vue-slick-carousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-slider-component

I am using the [vue-slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slick-carousel) package
in Vue js app i want to change slider dots styles change color, background, width, height and so on how can i achieve this? here is my code

```
<VueSlickCarousel :arrows="false" :dots="true" :slidesToShow="3">
  <div class="medium_rectangle">1</div>

  <div class="medium_rectangle">2</div>

  <div class="medium_rectangle">3</div>

  <div class="medium_rectangle">4</div>
</VueSlickCarousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what currently sets those values:

```
.slick-dots {
  background-color: transparent; /* bg color of container */
}
.slick-dots button:before {
  color: #000; /* color of dots */
  opacity: .25; /* opacity of dots */
  background-color: transparent; /* bg color of each "button" 
                                  * (blends with the one set in .slick-dots
                                  * if opacity is not 1) */
  content: "•"; /* this is the actual dot (yep, it's text)
                 * set it to ❥,  or whatever other string you want); 
             NOTE: don't set it to `none`: the dots won't display! */
  font-size: 10px; /* font-size of the dot */
}
.slick-dots .slick-active button:before {
  /* everything already listed under `.slick-dots button:before`
     except `opacity` is set to 1 by default */
}
```

Be weary the specificity of selectors currently setting those values is rather high. For example, in the case of the active dot opacity, it's `4 x classes + 2 x element` (example: `.slick-slider[data-v-aa003c28] .slick-dots .slick-active button:before`).
I typically use an `1 x :not(#id)` to override those (overrides without using `!important`).

Example *SCSS* (needs parsing!) which would apply:

```
.slick-dots:not(#_) {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.21);
  button:before {
    color: cyan;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  slick-active button:before {
    color: fuchsia;
  }

/* rounded dark container around dots */

  display: flex !important; /* override inline style ! */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: auto; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: .25rem;
}
```

Ends up like this:

[image: slick dots dark]

**Note**: I'm not telling you how to fight your own CSS specificity wars, I'm only showing you how I typically fight mines. Others use `!important`, others like to match the exact current specificity for each rule they override.
You do your own thing.

Comment: Where can I apply these styles? in the same file as my sliders? It's just that I tried it, nothing has changed, maybe you need to add! `Important` at the end?

Comment: You can add them anywhere in your SCSS, but if it's a `scoped` block you need to wrap them into a `::v-deep { /* code here */ }` block. Otherwise they don't apply, because the elements are inside `VueSlickCarousel` which is outside the CSS scope of your component.